# In python, how to transform the string slash to a escape sequence

Tags: python, escaping

I would like to know how to transform a string containing a Unicode ASCII descriptor into an actual Unicode character.

For example, how can I transform u"\\u1234" to u"\u1234" ?

Thank you.

Comment: And how is `u"\u1234"` different from `u"\u1234"`?

Comment: sorry, I don't notice that stackoverflow transform "\\" to "\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decode('unicode-escape')`, for example:

```
>>> s = u'\\u03be'
>>> s
u'\\u03be'
>>> print s
\u03be
>>> e = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> e
u'\u03be'
>>> print e
ξ
```

This works, but it would be better to fix the root of the problem. Where does the string come from in the first place? Is it JSON? Some Python code?

Comment: Thank you. I catch the html from a web and there are some Chinese characters  to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, using `ast.literal_eval`.  `ast.literal_eval` parses python literals *without* executing anycode embedded in it, so it's much safer to use in program.

The key idea is to evaluate a string representation of what you wish, for instance `u"\1234"`

```
import ast

s=u"\\u04d2"
s_bis=ast.literal_eval( u'u"'+s+u'"' )
```

edit: georg's solution is much better.